# ANR when writing to file for 2nd time

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I am logging errors to a file on the external storage of my device.  The first time I write to the file it works no problem.  However, the second time I get and ANR.  Here is the code:

```
PrintWriter writer;
try {   
    writer = new PrintWriter(
            new FileWriter(LOG_FILE_DIR + LOG_FILE, true)
        );

    while(e != null){
        e.printStackTrace(writer);
        e = e.getCause();
    }

    writer.println();
    writer.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the output from /data/anr/traces.txt:

```
----- pid 3859 at 2013-09-02 11:26:42 -----

DALVIK THREADS: (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=19 WAIT
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x416c6818 self=0x58260df0
    | sysTid=3888 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1477254904
    | state=S schedstat=( 5445000 16382000 49 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x416c6938> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=19 (AsyncTask #2)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-239" prio=5 tid=1 VMWAIT
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x416c6990 self=0x56de3010
    | sysTid=3859 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074619356
    | state=S schedstat=( 2408747000 339367000 1739 ) utm=148 stm=92 core=3
    #00  pc 00018104  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
    #01  pc 0000e41c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
    #02  pc 0000e478  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
    #03  pc 0004a4e9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #04  pc 0003a215  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #05  pc 00048429  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+452)
    #06  pc 00000db7  /system/bin/app_process
    #07  pc 0001271f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
    #08  pc 00000ae8  /system/bin/app_process
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=18 TIMED_WAIT
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x412854d8 self=0x57fa4f80
    | sysTid=3887 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1476019712
    | state=S schedstat=( 5789000 5521000 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x412c9f10> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=18 (pool-1-thread-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:911)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=17 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41290dc0 self=0x58114bb0
    | sysTid=3885 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1477292960
    | state=S schedstat=( 749000 177000 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
    #00  pc 00016fe4  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
    #01  pc 0002a9ad  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
    #02  pc 00016ba1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
    #03  pc 00017363  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
    #04  pc 0001b15d  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    #05  pc 00011267  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
    #06  pc 00047657  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
    #07  pc 00010dcd  /system/lib/libutils.so
    #08  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #09  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-235" prio=5 tid=16 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x412f0270 self=0x57fb1410
    | sysTid=3882 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1476072312
    | state=S schedstat=( 4084000 504000 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
    #00  pc 00018104  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
    #01  pc 0000e41c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
    #02  pc 0000e478  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
    #03  pc 001041f5  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #04  pc 0032f88f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #05  pc 0032f8eb  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #06  pc 0024e9e9  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #07  pc 001040b3  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #08  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #09  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-234" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x412df390 self=0x56e6adf0
    | sysTid=3880 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1457254064
    | state=S schedstat=( 127952000 36864000 136 ) utm=11 stm=1 core=3
    #00  pc 00017ee4  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
    #01  pc 0012b949  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    #02  pc 0012b755  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    #03  pc 000583ab  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    #04  pc 00056b13  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::RunInternal()+114)
    #05  pc 00056b71  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (MessageLoop::Run()+16)
    #06  pc 000771d9  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (base::Thread::ThreadMain()+188)
    #07  pc 00076c93  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
    #08  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #09  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-232" prio=5 tid=12 TIMED_WAIT
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x412c7038 self=0x586d1010
    | sysTid=3878 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1483543648
    | state=S schedstat=( 144000 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x412c5c70> (a org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$3)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$3.run(CordovaWebView.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x412abfc8 self=0x5a7979c8
    | sysTid=3876 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1508051320
    | state=S schedstat=( 3910000 23282000 28 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x412abcc8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AsyncTask #1)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x412a4eb8 self=0x5870ca68
    | sysTid=3874 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1506000736
    | state=S schedstat=( 527000 135000 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
    #00  pc 00017ee4  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
    #01  pc 00014b09  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
    #02  pc 00014d71  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
    #03  pc 0005fc1b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
    #04  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #05  pc 0004d489  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
    #06  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #07  pc 0002b5f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #08  pc 0005fdc9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
    #09  pc 0005fdf3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
    #10  pc 0005496f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #11  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #12  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
    at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
    at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41298db8 self=0x56e477c8
    | sysTid=3872 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1489447232
    | state=S schedstat=( 668477000 227888000 696 ) utm=53 stm=13 core=0
    #00  pc 00017ee4  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
    #01  pc 00014b09  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
    #02  pc 00014d71  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
    #03  pc 0005fc1b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
    #04  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #05  pc 0004d489  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
    #06  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #07  pc 0002b5f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #08  pc 0005fdc9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
    #09  pc 0005fdf3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
    #10  pc 0005496f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #11  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #12  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    #13  pc 0000c77c  <unknown>
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:920)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ef0750 self=0x5a78e0d0
    | sysTid=3871 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1483315936
    | state=S schedstat=( 4287000 1864000 13 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
    #00  pc 00016fe4  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
    #01  pc 0002a9ad  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
    #02  pc 00016ba1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
    #03  pc 00017363  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
    #04  pc 0001b15d  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    #05  pc 00011267  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
    #06  pc 00047657  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
    #07  pc 00010dcd  /system/lib/libutils.so
    #08  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #09  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40eed3b0 self=0x400ba600
    | sysTid=3870 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1359715720
    | state=S schedstat=( 6634000 4035000 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
    #00  pc 00016fe4  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
    #01  pc 0002a9ad  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
    #02  pc 00016ba1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
    #03  pc 00017363  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
    #04  pc 0001b15d  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    #05  pc 00011267  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
    #06  pc 00047657  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
    #07  pc 00010dcd  /system/lib/libutils.so
    #08  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #09  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
    | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee9fd0 self=0x585bf408
    | sysTid=3869 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1490720336
    | state=S schedstat=( 1012000 455000 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x40c8e5f0> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:230)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
    | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee9e20 self=0x5862d008
    | sysTid=3868 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1514179416
    | state=S schedstat=( 63627000 14162000 64 ) utm=6 stm=0 core=3
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x40c7a610> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
    | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee9cb8 self=0x587bf3c8
    | sysTid=3867 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1458334392
    | state=S schedstat=( 6227000 6534000 43 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x40c7a538> 
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
    at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:130)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
    | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee9bc8 self=0x56e67810
    | sysTid=3866 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1477360488
    | state=S schedstat=( 152410000 44911000 752 ) utm=9 stm=6 core=3
    #00  pc 00018104  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
    #01  pc 0000e41c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
    #02  pc 0000e478  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
    #03  pc 00072c85  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #04  pc 0005405b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #05  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #06  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
    | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee9ae0 self=0x586446c0
    | sysTid=3865 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1457404880
    | state=S schedstat=( 3200000 8133000 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
    #00  pc 0001710c  /system/lib/libc.so (select+20)
    #01  pc 00060c8b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #02  pc 0006381d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #03  pc 0005405b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #04  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #05  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

 "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
    | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee99e8 self=0x56e5ebe8
    | sysTid=3864 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1477364616
    | state=R schedstat=( 16076000 21692000 20 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
    | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee9908 self=0x58a14928
    | sysTid=3863 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1489737912
    | state=S schedstat=( 339909000 49610000 132 ) utm=33 stm=0 core=0
    #00  pc 00018104  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
    #01  pc 0000e41c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
    #02  pc 0000e478  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
    #03  pc 00071a37  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #04  pc 0005405b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #05  pc 0000e3d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #06  pc 0000dac4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

NATIVE THREADS:
"WebViewCoreThre" sysTid=3875 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
    | state=S schedstat=( 512000 0 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3

"SignalSender" sysTid=3877 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
    | state=S schedstat=( 10025000 25432000 166 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=0

"[my package id]" sysTid=3881 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
    | state=S schedstat=( 43000 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3

"TexturesGenerat" sysTid=3886 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
    | state=S schedstat=( 248008000 76502000 297 ) utm=17 stm=7 core=0

----- end 3859 -----
```

UPDATE:  I am only getting this when my handler for setUncaughtExceptionHandler is called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be a problem with your code, but note take that `e.printStackTrace(writer);` already does what you want, if the `Throwable` contains a cause,  the method will be invoked recursively for the nested `Throwable` and print the corresponding stacktrace, making your `while` loop unnecessary.

You can try without the `while` loop and check that there is no cycle between the exceptions (that is if `e` and `t` are exceptions and `e.getCause()` is `t` then make sure and `t.getCause()` is different than `e`)

Answer (score 0):

Make your logging method synchronized to avoid problems with writing from several threads to one file